# React Native searchbar with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header, searchbar

I would like to add a searchbar in my header. I am using react-navigation, and want to create an effect like in the below 2 pictures. When you press the search icon, the hamburger icon becomes a arrow-back icon, the header title becomes a search field. I have tried to accomplish this with the navigationOptions but the problem is that it is static and it cannot be updated when an action happens on the header itself. So for experimenting what I want to accomplish is that when the search icon is pressed, the hamburger icon becomes a arrow-back icon. Thank you!

```
var search = false;

const menuButton = navData => (
    <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item 
            title="Menu"
            iconName="ios-menu"
            onPress={() => {
                navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
            }}
        />
    </HeaderButtons>
);

const goBackButton = navData => (
    <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item 
            title="Menu"
            iconName="ios-arrow-back"
            onPress={() => {
                search=false
            }}
        />
    </HeaderButtons>
);

MyScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
    return {
        headerTitle: 'My title',
        headerLeft: search ? goBackButton : menuButton(navData),
        headerRight: (
            <BorderlessButton
            onPress={() => search=true}
            style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
            <Ionicons
                name="md-search"
                size={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 22 : 25}
            />
            </BorderlessButton>
        )
    }
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried with custom headers? i ve usualy disabled headers of react navigations and did my own custom header

Comment: I am new to React Native so I was trying to use as much existing components as possible. But so there is no easy workaround to get it working with react-navigation? The way to build this would be with custom headers?

Comment: yes , i would give a custom header which ive implemented in some time

Comment: Custom header is the way to go. I would also recommend learning Redux, so when you click on your header the state changes and depending on the state your icons etc change. This is a scalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

try use state bro !

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             search:false
        }
   }
const menuButton = navData => (
    <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item 
            title="Menu"
            iconName="ios-menu"
            onPress={() => {
                navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
            }}
        />
    </HeaderButtons>
);

const goBackButton = navData => (
    <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item 
            title="Menu"
            iconName="ios-arrow-back"
            onPress={() => {this.setState({search:false})}}
        />
    </HeaderButtons>
);

MyScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
    return {
        headerTitle: 'My title',
        headerLeft: this.state.search ? goBackButton : menuButton(navData),
        headerRight: (
            <BorderlessButton
            onPress={() => {this.setState({search:true})}}
            style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
            <Ionicons
                name="md-search"
                size={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 22 : 25}
            />
            </BorderlessButton>
        )
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by passing information to my navigationOptions with setParams and getParam. The only problem I faced was in infinite loop which I could solve with the proper use of useEffect and useCallback.

```
const MyScreen = props => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    var search = useSelector(state => state.verbs.search);
    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.setParams({search: search});
    }, [search]);

    const toggleSearchHandler = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(toggleSearch());
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.setParams({toggleSearch: toggleSearchHandler});
    }, [toggleSearchHandler]);
    return (<View> ...
    </View>
  );
};

MyScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
    const toggleSearch = navData.navigation.getParam('toggleSearch')
    return {
        headerTitle: 'Verbs',
        headerLeft: navData.navigation.getParam('search') ? gobackButton : menuButton(navData),
        headerRight: (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item 
                    title="Menu"
                    iconName="ios-star"
                    onPress={toggleSearch}
                />
            </HeaderButtons>
        )
    }
};
```